# serverless nodejs generate image using canvas

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

I am creating images using https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas

It works great in local but when I deploy it the unzipped source are more than 250M so it fail.

I tried to use https://github.com/jwerre/node-canvas-lambda to generate two layers, once the layers generated I used it as follow

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  region: eu-west-1
  layers:
      - arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxx:layer:node16Canvas:1
      - arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxx:layer:node16CanvasLib64:1
```

I do not really understand how the layer work, it seems I can use `node_module` from a layer, but I don't know if I need extra config

I added `canvas` into the dev dependencies, so it is not included into the package. But I have the following error

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'canvas' imported from /var/task/handler.js
```

Comment: I'm getting same issue. Trying to create the zip files from my MAC. Dis you solve this issue?